# MySQL Advice : huge database constantly updated but want to also search results to a website

Tags: mysql, synchronization, replication

I currently have a database with about 5 million rows of data which each row is being updated with data daily.  I am doing nearly 200,000 rows an hour of updates, so I have my tables as an InnoDB.  Now I already know this is my master database, but I also need to report all this information back to a website for mostly SELECTS (basically very few updates / inserts / deletes).

My question is, what is likely the best option for me?  A 12-24 hour delay in data is completely acceptable so should I have a Master -> Slave type situation?  Should I dump the master database every 12 hours and simply replace the website's version as needed sending the few updates / deletes to a SQL text file I execute first?

This is a project that will grow quickly over the next 12 months so I really want to make the best selection now.  Our database is flying as we have an extremely powerful server for it, but I want to make sure once we launch the site, it's also optimized. An example is if we dump the db daily and replace the old one, then I got to consider the few updates that would happen.  If a Master/Slave setup is more ideal for this, can you provide links to some docs that would help me best optimize my setup?

Comment: at my job the dbadmin uses data (not query) replication for a master/slave setup, and it works great - I'm not sure how simple that is to configure, but I believe it's just in the my.cnf.

Comment: Is the website presenting the data like its coming on or are you doing a fair amount of joins / sums?  If the latter, then I'd suggest you set up a data warehouse to maintain the bits you want to keep and let the website pull from it.

Comment: Replication is what I was going to look into, cause I have consulted with someone on this before. Just not sure exactly how to do it.

Comment: There will be joins, not really any math (sums).  Data will not just be displayed as is, though I did do my best to use as little joins as possible, and also did the best possible indexing I could think of.  As for a data warehouse to maintain the bits I need, not exactly sure what that means? I will be doing a lot of cacheing of end result data so i dont have to select the same data multiple times in a given time period, however im more concerned right now about the best way to handle the multiple databases (if I should even do two)

Answer (score 0):

You can turn on bin logging (which you would have on with a master setup, anyway) then manually (or via a cronjob) [FLUSH LOGS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/flush.html) and ship the last binlog(s) to the read slave (say, every 12+ hours).

At this point, you can use standard mysql tools (mysqlbinlog) to read the log and import it to your read instance

mysqlbinlog /path/to/binlog | mysql -u -p

Make sure you read the notes [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/point-in-time-recovery.html) around issues with passing multiple binlogs to the mysqlbinlog command.

This method assumes the read host is synchronized with a full snapshot of the database prior to beginning this method.